# Change button background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

After several attempts to change the background of a button, and getting errors of casting and things like that I finnaly got to this point:

```
Uri dir = new Uri("red_flag.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
ImageSource source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(dir);
ImageBrush bru = new ImageBrush();
bru.ImageSource=source;
bru.Opacity = 100;
```

This code does not generate errors, but I can't see the changes when I call:

```
button1.background = bru;
```

It just makes anything! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the answer myelf after reading Mick's answer, I share with you what I did:

```
Uri dir = new Uri("red_flag.png", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(dir);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = source;
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
stack.Children.Add(image);
myButton.Content = stack;
```

Thanks for your help

Update 1:
For best results set the padding property of your button to 0 (in each of the cases) so the image can resize automatically to fill all the button, please note this could hide your actual content, in my case this was what I wanted.

Comment: For best results set the padding property of your button to 0 (in each of the cases) so the image can resize automatically to fill all the button, please note this could hide your actual content, in my case this was what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If this code is part of the click event handler for the same button you will have this problem.

Peter Torr explains why here and offers a solution.

[Why can't I change the Background of my Button on a Click event?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: But that needs me to declare the buttonson the XAML x_X, the nature of my program requieres me to create the buttons programatically

Comment: How does creating a style based on the xaml that Blend generates work out for you, then assign it programatically per - http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/13115/42706.aspx